# How to dynamic connect database using Spring 3.2 and JPA 2.0

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-jdbc

I am using spring 3.2.3 and JPA 2.0. I want to dynamic connect my database base on enum. I have configuration like this

```
<bean id="legacyDataSource" name="myLegacyDataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource" lazy-init="true">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.legacy.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.legacy.url}" />  
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.legacy.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.legacy.password}" />
</bean>

 <bean id="modernDataSource" name="myModernDataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource" lazy-init="true">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.modern.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.modern.url}" />  
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.modern.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.modern.password}" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="emf"/>
</bean>

<bean id="placeholderProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location" value="classpath:database/jdbc.properties" />
    <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE" />
    <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true" />
    <property name="order" value="1" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<bean id="emf" name="myEmf" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" lazy-init="true">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="vendorAdaptor" />         
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.softech.ls360.integration.regulators.plcb.domain"/>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.max_fetch_depth">3</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size">50</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">10</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>              
        </props>        
    </property>
</bean>
```

I declared the enum like

```
public enum DatabaseType {

    LEGACY,
    MODERN

} //end of enum DatabaseType
```

Now i want in my main class on the basis of enum the database switches. For this i think i need to change the

```
<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
```

in the `<bean id="emf" name="myEmf" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" lazy-init="true">` at runtime. Am i right ?

Is there any way to do it or is spring provide any other way to switch database on runtime ?

I found this article [Dynamic DataSource Routing](http://blog.springsource.org/2007/01/23/dynamic-datasource-routing/) but this is very old post and also in this post no JPA is used. Kindly help

Thanks.

**EDIT
--------------------------------**

```
@Lazy
@Service("dbManager") 
@Repository
@Transactional
public class DatabaseManager {

    public enum EnumLmsPlateform {      
        MODERN,
        LEGACY;
    }

    private EnumLmsPlateform lmsPlatform;

    public EnumLmsPlateform getLmsPlatform() {
        return lmsPlatform;
    }

    public void setLmsPlatform(EnumLmsPlateform lmsPlatform) {
        this.lmsPlatform = lmsPlatform;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {    
        setLmsPlatform(EnumLmsPlateform.MODERN);    
    }

    @PersistenceContext(unitName="legacy_emf")
    private EntityManager legacyEm;

    @PersistenceContext(unitName="modern_emf")
    private EntityManager ls360Em;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Transactional(readOnly=true)
    public List<Object> getResultList(String query, Class<?> mappingClass) throws Exception {

        EntityManager em = null;

        if (lmsPlatform == EnumLmsPlateform.LEGACY) {
            em = legacyEm;  
        } else if (lmsPlatform == EnumLmsPlateform.MODERN){ 
            em = ls360Em;   
        }
        Query emQuery = em.createNativeQuery(query, mappingClass);  
        return  emQuery.getResultList();

    } //end of findTraineeFromLegacy()
} //end of class
```

Here is my spring file

legacy-spring.xml

```
<bean id="legacyDataSource" name="legacy_DataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource" lazy-init="true">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.legacy.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.legacy.url}" />  
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.legacy.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.legacy.password}" />
</bean>

<bean id="legacyTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" lazy-init="true">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="legacyEmf"/>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="legacyTransactionManager"  />

<bean id="legacyEmf" name="legacy_emf" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" lazy-init="true" >
    <property name="dataSource" ref="legacyDataSource" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="vendorAdaptor" />         
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.softech.ls360.integration.regulators.plcb.domain"/>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.max_fetch_depth">3</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size">50</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">10</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>              
        </props>        
    </property>
</bean>
```

same file is for moderns-spring.xml

then i am including both file in my maim spring

app-context.xml

```
<import resource="classpath:database/hibernate-context.xml"/>
<import resource="classpath:database/legacyJpa-context.xml"/>
<import resource="classpath:database/modernJpa-context.xml"/> 

<context:annotation-config/>
....
```

But there is one flow in this design. Both the managers are including. Legacy and Modern. I mean when my dbManager bean is initialized then it needs both `@PersistenceContext(unitName="legacy_emf"), @PersistenceContext(unitName="modern_emf")`. What should happen that as my default `persistence context` is modern so only  `@PersistenceContext(unitName="modern_emf")` this persistence context should be available when bean initialized. Then if i set my `enum to legacy` then  `unitName="legacy_emf"` this should be available. Did u get me ?

Thanks

**Edit 2:
---------------------------------------------------------------------**

I changed my dbManager class below

```
@Lazy
@Service("dbManager") 
@Repository
@Transactional
public class DatabaseManager {

    public enum EnumLmsPlateform {
        MODERN,
        LEGACY;
    }

    private EnumLmsPlateform lmsPlatform;

    public DatabaseManager() {

    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        setLmsPlatform(EnumLmsPlateform.MODERN);
    }


    public EnumLmsPlateform getLmsPlatform() {
        return lmsPlatform;
    }

    public void setLmsPlatform(EnumLmsPlateform lmsPlatform) {
        this.lmsPlatform = lmsPlatform;
    }

    @ModernTx
    public List<Object> getModernResultSet(String query, Class<?> mappingClass) { 
        EntityManager modernEm = getEntityManagerFormBoundTransactionalThread();
        return getResultSet(modernEm, query, mappingClass);

    }

    @LegacyTx 
    public List<Object> getLegacyResultSet(String query, Class<?> mappingClass) { 
        EntityManager legacyEm = getEntityManagerFormBoundTransactionalThread();
        return getResultSet(legacyEm, query, mappingClass);
    } 

    @Transactional 
    public List<Object> getDefaultResultSet(String query, Class<?> mappingClass) { 
        EntityManager defaultEm = getEntityManagerFormBoundTransactionalThread();
        return getResultSet(defaultEm, query, mappingClass);
    }

    private List<Object> getResultSet(EntityManager em, String query, Class<?> mappingClass) {
        Query emQuery = em.createNativeQuery(query, mappingClass);  
        return  emQuery.getResultList();    
    }

    private EntityManager getEntityManagerFormBoundTransactionalThread(){
        Map<Object, Object>  map =   TransactionSynchronizationManager.getResourceMap();   
        for (Object value  :map.values()) {
            if(value instanceof EntityManagerHolder){       
                return ((EntityManagerHolder)value).getEntityManager();

            }  
        } 

        return null;  

    } //end of  getEntityManagerFormBoundTransactionalThread()  

} //end of class
```

My test class

```
public class TestDynamicJpa {

    String springXmlFile = "classpath:spring/app-context-xml.xml";

    GenericXmlApplicationContext springContext = SpringUtil.loadSpringContext(springXmlFile);

    List<Object> traineeList = getLegacyResultList(springContext);

    private List<Object> getLegacyResultList(GenericXmlApplicationContext springContext) throws Exception {

        DatabaseManager dbManager = springContext.getBean("dbManager", DatabaseManager.class);

        List<Object> resultList = dbManager.getLegacyResultSet(FIND_TRAINEE_LEGACY, LegacyTrainee.class);

        return resultList;

    } //end of getLegacyResultList()

} //end of class TestDynamicJpa
```

One question. When i do

```
List<Object> resultList = dbManager.getLegacyResultSet(FIND_TRAINEE_LEGACY, LegacyTrainee.class);
```

Then it gets the `LegacyTransactionManager` from Map, fine. But if i do

```
List<Object> resultList = dbManager.getDefaultResultSet(FIND_TRAINEE_LEGACY, LegacyTrainee.class);
```

Then which transaction manager it gets from Map. `Legacy` or `Modern` ?

Also i checked it with this configuration also

```
 <import resource="classpath:database/hibernate-context.xml"/>
 <import resource="classpath:database/legacyJpa-context.xml"/>
 <!--  
 <import resource="classpath:database/ls360Jpa-context.xml"/> 
 -->
```

i.e., import only one Jpa context, and it's working fine :). While with my previous `@PersistenceUnit` configuration i get the error if i comment out the one file :).

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case as you have 2 more datasource, you should create 2 more transactionManager with different names.

```
<bean id="legacyTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="emfLegacy"/>
</bean>


<bean id="modernTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="emfModern"/>
</bean>

<bean id="emfLegacy" name="myEmfLegacy" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" lazy-init="true">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="legacyDataSource" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="vendorAdaptor" />         
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.softech.ls360.integration.regulators.plcb.domain"/>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.max_fetch_depth">3</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size">50</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">10</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>              
        </props>        
    </property>
</bean>   



<bean id="emfModern" name="myEmfModern" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" lazy-init="true">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="modernDataSource" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="vendorAdaptor" />         
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.softech.ls360.integration.regulators.plcb.domain"/>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.max_fetch_depth">3</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size">50</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">10</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>              
        </props>        
    </property>
</bean>   



 @Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Transactional("modernTransactionManager")
public @interface ModernTx {
}

@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Transactional("legacyTransactionManager")
public @interface LegacyTx {
}
```

After that the rest is easy just annotate your bean's db methods with @ModernTx or @LegacyTx as below.

```
public class TransactionalService {

    @ModernTx
    public void setSomething(String name) { 

         EntityManager currentEm = getEntityManagerFormBoundTransactionalThread();
         /*You can do anything with this Modern em*/
    }

    @LegacyTx 
    public void doSomething() { 

         EntityManager currentEm = getEntityManagerFormBoundTransactionalThread();
         /*You can do anything with this Legacy em*/

    } 


    @Transactional 
    public void buySomething() { 

         EntityManager currentEm = getEntityManagerFormBoundTransactionalThread();
         /*You can do anything with this default em*/

    }         




   private getEntityManagerFormBoundTransactionalThread(){

        Map<Object, Object>  map =                    TransactionSynchronizationManager.getResourceMap();
        for (Object value  :map.values()) {
            if(value instanceof EntityManagerHolder){
                            return ((EntityManagerHolder)value).getEntityManager();
                }
            }
            }     
     }
```

However when you want your dafult datasource to be used, just use @Transactional since you have configured default transaction manager as below in your context.

Comment: Hi thanks. Kindly check my edit. I have done exactly what you said. Can you explain me what are those annotations `@ModernTx` and ` @LegacyTx`. Do they switch on basis of enum ?

Comment: you declare that if you use @transactional only you will use this transaction manager <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/> for this txmanager you also declared "myemf" as I see above in your XML. And myemf use "datasource" . You configured it some where but I can not see it here.

Comment: Probably "datasource" bean id is in "classpath:database/hibernate-context.xml"

Comment: Yes datasource bean id is in `hibernate-context.xml`. Actually i did it because if i want to use another persistence provider vendor then i just create another file like `eclipselink-context.xml` and provide their reference. Actually that `<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>` is old one. `Edit 1` contains new configuration file `legacy-spring.xml` same file is for `mpdern-spring.xml` only pointing to modern database ... Anyways but you solved my problem. Only last question remains that `which transaction manager it gets from Map. Legacy or Modern ?`

Comment: you should have an exception like below if you just use @Transactional I have tried know :)                         Exception in thread main org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: legacyTransactionManager,legacyTransactionManager